# push notification module sending null

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send notification to registered devices using gcm. But it send "null" instead of message. I have tried lot of solutions. If any basic thing is missing kindly share. I have attached the code spinet.

```
        JSONObject jGcmData = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject jData = new JSONObject();
        String msg = "new order came";
        jData.put("message", msg);
        // Where to send GCM message.
        if (!(id == null)) {
            jGcmData.put("to", id);
        } else {
            jGcmData.put("to", "/topics/global");
        }
        // What to send in GCM message.
        jGcmData.put("data", jData);

        // Create connection to send GCM Message request.
        URL url = new URL("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + API_KEY);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        // Send GCM message content.
        OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(jGcmData.toString().getBytes());
```

Answer (score 0):

The url you are using is incorrect. It should be `https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send`. See [Server changes](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/c2dm#server).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valid reply. But still it showing null.